# Ruby on Rails (Redmine) on Apache - 503 Error

Tags: apache-2.2, ruby-on-rails, redmine, 503-error

I am running a Ruby on Rails application called Redmine. It's been working fine, but today it's giving a 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable error. (It was initially set up by an employee who is now gone.)

I check the error log and it says:

```
[Mon Nov 21 11:03:30 2011] [error] (111)Connection refused: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:3000 (127.0.0.1) failed
[Mon Nov 21 11:03:30 2011] [error] ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (127.0.0.1)
```

Here's a chunk of my Apache config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName redmine.{domain}.com
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ balancer://redminecluster%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,L]
</VirtualHost>

<Proxy balancer://redminecluster>
  BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:3000
</Proxy>
```

I found this link: http://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/20561 which suggests I simply need to "start the redmine server." I've tried `/etc/init.d/redmine start` which gives me this output

```
=> Booting Mongrel
=> Rails 2.3.11 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
```

The contents of /etc/init.d/redmine:

```
cd /var/redmine
sudo ruby script/server -d -e production
```

One thing I immediately notice is that it says 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1. In addition, running `top` or `ps -ef` shows no record of a "mongrel" or "redmine" process. I've also tried restarting Apache before and after starting redmine. Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Running `netstat -ptan` and checking what's listening on port 3000 will tell you what the name of your Mongrel process is. It's usually `mongrel_rails` or something similar, but it's conceivable it could be `ruby` or another name.

Comment: Thanks - I tried that and there is nothing running on port 3000. Must mean /etc/init.d/redmine is failing somehow.

Comment: @jgoldschrafe I figured it out thanks to your help. You should add an answer so that I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured it out, thanks to [jgoldschrafe](https://serverfault.com/users/58656/jgoldschrafe). I tried `netstat -ptan` and found that there was no Mongrel process running on port 3000 as there should have been, indicating that `/etc/init.d/redmine` was failing. Indeed, I removed the `-d` (debug) flag and found that there was a large error backtrace regarding a plugin that was installed recently. I removed the plugin and all is well now.